# text_wrap format gets ignored using worksheet formatting

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Wrap text does not work for me. I tried the below code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
df_input.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inputs')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet_input = writer.sheets['Inputs']
header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
worksheet_input.set_row(1,45,header_format )
```

Here is the screenshot of my result

[image]

Wrap text does not work for me. I tried the below code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
df_input.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inputs')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet_input = writer.sheets['Inputs']
header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
worksheet_input.set_row(1,45,header_format )
```

Here is the screenshot of my result

[image]

Got the below error using @amanb's solution/code
[image]

My dataframe looks something like below

[image]

Comment: Is this referring to `xlsxwriter`? Can you show what you trying to add to the cell and show an image of how it looks? The default behaviour of `'text_wrap':True` is to wrap the text and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I have updated the information

Comment: I added an answer that may help.

Answer (score 6):

According to the official documentation for [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html):

> Pandas writes the dataframe header with a default cell format. Since it is a cell format it cannot be overridden using [set_row()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#set_row). If you wish to use your own format for the headings then the best approach is to turn off the automatic header from Pandas and write your own.

So, we turn off the automatic header from Pandas and write our own. The defined `header_format` should be applied to each column header in the `df_input` and written to the worksheet. The following is customized to your requirement and a similar example is shown in the official docs.

```
# Turn off the default header and skip one row to allow us to insert a
# user defined header.
df_input.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inputs', startrow=1, header=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Inputs']

# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df_input.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
```

Comment: I,m getting the below error: `TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'tuple'> in write()`

Comment: Please show the full Traceback error. Most likely the dataframe `df_input` has a tuple value

Comment: Its not clear which one of the values is a tuple(`col_num` or `value` in the `for` loop). I'm suspecting it has to be some `value` in the dataframe `df_input`. Can you `print(col_num, value)` inside the for loop and notice if a tuple is found? Or can you show what `df_input` looks like?

Comment: Yes it's the values which is tuple since I have multi header dataframe.

Comment: Updated the question with the dataframe screenshot