# text wrap ignores heading rows

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I tried the below code for text wrapping,, It wraps text starting from row 3 and not getting applied on row 1,2 which is the header

```
worksheet = writer.sheets['Inputs']
text_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
for row in range(0, 100):
    worksheet.set_row(row , 25, text_format)
```

I have attached the screenshot here

[image]

Comment: The `set_row()` doesn't work for row 1 and 2 because they already have a cell format (the blue format). In terms of priority a cell format overrides a row format.

Comment: Didn't you get an answer to this question [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183760/text-wrap-format-gets-ignored-using-worksheet-formatting)?